# MKAnnotation not responding on tap

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I am displaying several pins on map just like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < points.count; i++) {
    if([[[points objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"lat"] class] != [NSNull class]) {
        southWest.latitude = MAX(southWest.latitude , [[[points objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue]);
        southWest.longitude = MIN(southWest.longitude, [[[points objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"lon"] doubleValue]);
        northEast.latitude = MIN(northEast.latitude, [[[points objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue]);
        northEast.longitude = MAX(northEast.longitude, [[[points objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"lon"] doubleValue]);

        pin.latitude = [[[points objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
        pin.longitude = [[[points objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"lon"] doubleValue];
        CarPin *cPin = [[CarPin alloc] initWithName:[[self.brain.cars objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"] state:[self getStateStringFor:[[[points objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"state"] intValue]] coordinate:pin];
        cPin.state = [[[points objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"state"] intValue];
        cPin.carID = [[points objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"objekt_id"];
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:cPin];
    }
}

CLLocation *locSouthWest = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:southWest.latitude longitude:southWest.longitude];
CLLocation *locNorthEast = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:northEast.latitude longitude:northEast.longitude];
CLLocationDistance meters = [locSouthWest distanceFromLocation:locNorthEast];

MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.latitude = (southWest.latitude + northEast.latitude) / 2.0;
region.center.longitude = (southWest.longitude + northEast.longitude) / 2.0;
region.span.latitudeDelta = meters / 111319.5;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.0;

[self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
```

THEN I choose "look" of each pin like this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
static NSString *identifier = @"CarPin";
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CarPin class]]) {
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    } else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    if (((CarPin *)annotation).state == 1) {
        annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    } else {
        annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    }
    return annotationView;
}
return nil;
}
```

I also set the delegate

```
[self.mapView setDelegate:self];
```

BUT, when I click on each pin, I get no bubble displayed on screen with details! Anybody experiencing the same?

Comment: Does your CarPin implement the "title" property? I believe you have to set a value for the title property otherwise you won't see the callout.

Comment: Yes it does, the Car Pin is copied from project for iPhone, where it already works.

Comment: You have to make sure `title` is not coming out nil or blank.  Show the CarPin.m.  Also, the `CarPin *cPin = [[CarPin alloc]...` line has way too much stuff going on in that one line for you or anyone to easily understand what's going on and _most importantly for you to easily debug it_ -- split it up into multiple lines.  Most likely the title method in CarPin.m is returning nil or blank because one of the init parameters is blank.  Also, use MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance instead of trying to set latitudeDelta manually from meters to degrees.  Calling regionThatFits is also unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you Anna! The title actually WAS nil, which made it not respond. Could you please ellaborate and post your hints as answer so I can implement what you're saying and then accept the answer to close this topic? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply implementing the `title` property is not enough.
You have to make sure that `title` is not returning `nil` or blank.
If it is, the annotation view will not display a callout even if `canShowCallout` is set to `YES`.

Unrelated to your issue but regarding this line:

```
region.span.latitudeDelta = meters / 111319.5;
```

This is not recommended and unnecessary for at least three reasons:

- Calculating the meter distance between the two corners (for which you have the latitude and longitude in *degrees* and then converting those meters back to *degrees*) is unecessary because `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta` is simply the difference in degrees between the top/bottom or left/right.  So all you have to do is:

  ```
  region.span.latitudeDelta = fabs(southWest.latitude - northEast.latitude);
  ```

  This is the change I would recommend in your case.
- The value you are dividing by to convert meters to degrees (`111319.5`) will only be accurate at the equator.
- If you want to specify a region based on meters, instead of calculating the span in degrees manually, it's much better and easier to use the built-in [`MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008209-CH2-SW5) function:

  ```
  CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake (lat, long);
  CLLocationDistance latMeters = 5000;  //5 km
  CLLocationDistance lonMeters = 5000;  //5 km
  MKCoordinateRegion region 
      = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance (center, latMeters, lonMeters);
  ```

Also, calling `regionThatFits` is unnecessary in your case because the `setRegion` will already do this itself with whatever region you pass it.  The `regionThatFits` method is used when you want to know (without actually changing the region) what the map view would adjust the region to given a certain region.

Comment: That is a remarkale answer. I am very grateful for hints, will do :)